# Automatic Message sending at a particular time

Tags: android

I am developing an application where i need to send an sms to a particular phone number. I can send the sms using following code.

```
try {
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, sms, null, null);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "SMS faild, please try again later!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Now what i want is the sms should go automatically. The time, at which the message should go automatically, is stored in MySQL database.So i need the code that will keep on checking when that time comes and then send the message to that number automatically. Its a kind of reminder thing. The user will keep a reminder in application eg.; i need to get a message after 1 hour. So after 1 hour the message should come. PLz help??

Finally i got it.

```
/** Code For reminder is here */
            int time=Integer.parseInt(answer);
            int num = (int)System.currentTimeMillis();  
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(), MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
            intent.putExtra("phoneNo",phoneNo);   
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, time);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                getApplicationContext(), num, intent, 0);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()
                + calendar.getTimeInMillis() , pendingIntent);
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Alarm set in " + time + " minutes",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            /** Code for reminder is over */
```

And my reciever code is

```
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String sms= "Your turn is about to come. Please be ready. Thank You";
    String phoneNo;
    Bundle extrasBundle = intent.getExtras();
    phoneNo=extrasBundle.getString("phoneNo");
    try {
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, sms, null, null);
        Toast.makeText(context, "SMS Sent to " + phoneNo,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(context,"SMS faild, please try again later!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

}

Just in case someone might need this... Thanku

Comment: can you please tell me where did you write `/** Code For reminder */`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) for this purpose. Create a receiver, register it in manifest file. 
with alarmaManager set an Alarm after particular time.
put your SendSMS code into Receiver's on receive.

Edit : I answered this long back, it is not suitable for current scenarios, please read this blog for better alternatives [Background schedulers](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/choosing-the-right-background-scheduler-in-android/) instead.

Comment: @Ankit can you please tell me where should I write `/** Code For reminder */`

Answer (score 2):

Alarmmanager helps you to call at a specific time,Use AlarmManager and put all your code of send message in BroadcastReceiver's OnReceivemethod . Follow this [Link](http://ashimita.blogspot.in/2012/04/broadcast-receiver-change-in-flow-since.html). Also remember to alter manifest file. All the best :)

Comment: @Ankit sorry dude i din look at to your answer as i opened window to post answer and get busy in another work. !!